# UITableVIew multiple section and single row selection in each section

Tags: uitableview, sections

I have table view which contain 7 sections and each section has different number of rows. The problem is when I select a row in section and check mark. Others sections rows are also checked mark and when I scroll the table. then unwanted check marks are appeared. It show very goofy behavior.

If you have any tutorial or sample code, please share it with me.